# css3, cannot put a div centralized

Tags: html, css, menu, alignment, centering

I cannot put my menu in the center of the page, i've inserted all "margin: 0 auto;" i can and all "text-align: center", and the div is separated from everything, is not a child of something else..
here's the css code:

```
.more{
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
clear:both;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 20px 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 40%;
height: 20%;
}
.more ul{
display:block;
text-align:center;
}
.more ul li{
display: block;
padding: 10px 3px;
float:left;
}
.more ul li.selected a,
.more ul li.selected a:hover{
background:#0099c5;
color:#fff;
text-shadow:none;
font-weight:bold;
}
.more ul li a{
color:#555;
float:left;
background:#fff;
width: 100%;
padding: 8px 10px;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #aaa;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #aaa;
box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #aaa;
}
.more ul li a:hover{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
```

And here's the HTML code:

```
             <div class="more">
                <ul>
                    <li class="selected"><a href="#">Homepage Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#1">Cerca</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#2">Archivio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#3">Tags</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

How-to make the div permanently in the center of my page? I've tried lot, lot, lot of possible moves.

Thank you.

p.s. I've also tried to put a `<div align=center> ...my menu (class=more) list ...</div>`

Comment: Seems to be in the middle for me: http://jsfiddle.net/44Pk4/

Comment: Please, share more html code. http://jsfiddle.net/m6v35/

Comment: it seems. Try to delete the `width: 40%;` in the .more css code.

Comment: If you need it horizontally and vertical you can try this, http://jsfiddle.net/bFMV9/ or http://jsfiddle.net/bFMV9/1/.

Comment: How about removing the floats and using `inline-block` display? Like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/44Pk4/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/44Pk4/1/)

Comment: Thank you Harry, but already answered Stefano. Thanks a lot however :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that you can't use margin:0 auto on floatted element.

Keys for margin 0 auto are:

1) element must have display:block
2) no float, absolute or fixed position

```
.more{
float:left;
clear:both;
font-size: 13px;
padding: 20px 0px;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 100%;
height: 20%;
}
.more ul{
display:block;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
}
.more ul li{
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 3px;
}
.more ul li.selected a,
.more ul li.selected a:hover{
background:#0099c5;
color:#fff;
text-shadow:none;
font-weight:bold;
}
.more ul li a{
color:#555;
background:#fff;
width: 100%;
padding: 8px 10px;
-moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #aaa;
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #aaa;
box-shadow:1px 1px 2px #aaa;
}
.more ul li a:hover{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: wow, perfect, so you'r saying that if I put a float, i cannot put a margin centered? ...lol, however thanks run perfectly. Correct answer!

Comment: His solution has no floating related to div.more and div's are displayed as BLOCK by default....

Comment: yes, when you use float:left/position:absolute/fixed you can't use margin:0 auto. if answer was fine, please accept it :) thanks

Comment: @adrian.krzysztofek ye i know div are block as default but he used margin 0 auto on li too and li are not block as default.

Comment: adrian.krzysztofek, his solution is what I need. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @LudovicoLoreti If you need your menu to float:left you can either give it to .more  becuase if your read the css im centering the ul inside .more

Comment: What i would use float left to now?

Comment: if for example you want to put a side-div with logo inside you can use float:left on .more (removing clear:both) and you box logo so both will be removed from usual flow and positioned one beside the other.